# Pivot count names by groups

Tags: excel, count, pivot-table

I have a PivotTable with a variety of personal names, you can then expand each person to find out if he is A, B, C , A and B, A and C , or B and C.

I want the number of A and B's specific, not just how many people have two letters.

So how I count the number of A and B , A and C's , and B and C's ?

Comment: I want the number of A and B's specific, not just how many persons who have 2 Letters

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate pivot table and put your field which contains {A,B,C,D} into the **Row Labels** and **Values** fields

Answer (score 0):

Taking your comment into consideration, I think what you want is the count of people numbers by category (ie assumes each person fits into only one type, even though the type may be 'compound'), for example:

[image: SO25886441 example]

where the left-hand columns represent your existing PivotTable. You *might* be able to achieve this result with a different view from your existing PT.